# "Besides for that" vs "Other than that"

Tags: idiomatic-language

I know a friend that always says:

> Besides for that.

I don't think this is grammatically correct. However, because of the nature of the sentence, I can't find anything which explains either way.

Is:

> Besides for that.

Grammatically correct?

or is:

> Other than that.

Correct?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, "besides that" is the correct form. But, this structure is possible also: "Besides, for that...".

Comment: *Besides for that* is not valid English, grammatically or idiomatically. Presumably your friend is not a native speaker - if he *is*, I'd say he's incredibly non-standard. Note that *on top of that* is also common in speech, and *additionally, furthermore* are good choices in more formal contexts. One colloquial idiomatic form that will also work well in many contexts is ***to boot***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not correct.  I do wonder if it's based on a misconstrual of ***aside from*** that, which would be correct.  **Other than that** is also fine.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to mean "in addition to", you can say besides that, other than that, apart from that, or aside from that.

It's incorrect to say "besides for that".

Answer (score 2):

"Other than that." is correct.

"Besides for that." is incorrect.

"Besides" doesn't need a preposition - in this sentence, we actually use "besides" *as* a preposition: "Besides that."

Answer (score 1):

Have you been reading an Ivy Smoak book? She uses "besides for" all the time and it makes me cringe every time I read it.

I could forgive the improper use of the English language if it was one uneducated character using the phrase. In her books, all    characters use it.

I wondered if it was a regional thing, but can't find any evidence of that. I'm guessing that she means

> 'except for'
> 'aside from'
> 'other than
> 'outside of'
> or just 'besides'

Whatever the case, I find myself correcting it in my head.